# Can't install Chrome on Windows 10,1803

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, windows-10-v1803

I just borrowed a PC which I believe had been factory reset to Windows 10. I finished that installation and installed all updates. Then the first thing I did was trying to install Google Chrome. I download the Google ChromeSetup.exe. Running it fails:

```
"Installation failed with an unspecified error. If Google Chrome is currently running, please close it and try again."
```

I have rebooted etc. I installed Firefox. Then downloaded ChromSetup.exe with Firefox. Same problem.

I suspect of course that this is another problem with 1803 (Windows 10), but I don't know.

EDIT: I sent a bug report.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=909067

Comment: This problem is not related to Windows 10 1803.  In order to properly identify the problem, the installation log must be provided which hopefully indicates something other than an unspecified error.  I would delete any Chrome related folders out of Program Files and AppData.

Comment: Try this offline installer: https://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?standalone=1&platform=win64

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, but there are no such folders.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks. I sent a bug report instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the application folder, then install it again.
1. Find the directory in your PC: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome
2. Delete the application folder. If you have difficulty deleting the folder, check for active google Chrome processes and end them.
3. Open Task scheduler and end all process that includes "google" or "chrome" in its name.
4. Delete the folder again.
5. Once the application folder is deleted, try installing Google chrome again.
You may refer to [this post in Google Chrome Help Forum.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/NK83WH7Ew60/JMw05VVks5kJ)

Comment: Thanks, but there are no such folders.

Answer (score -1):

It was another 1803 problem. See [the bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=909067).

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question, but this isn't an informative answer.  If you're convinced that it's a bug, it would be better to post the bug report here (rather than in the question), and also mention the gist in the answer.

Comment: I simply feel it's a case, where something fail to happen (what happened cannot be determined without the installation log), and the problem was fixed due to the reboot by the cumulative update.

Comment: @fixer1234 I am afraid that this is as good as it can be. Everything is in the bug report.

Comment: @Ramhound I am afraid you are wrong. Please read the bug report.